# Page is continuously getting refreshed automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, window.location

I have a react app where on loading the App component first the app checks whether there is token in localstorage, If it is there then it takes the token and verifies it, If the token is valid then the user is taken to dashboard and if it isn't the user is taken to login page, But however what is happening is that the page is getting continuosly refreshed, I have used window.location.href to redirect the user to other page, Am I doing something wrong please let me know I have posted the code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import setAuthToken from "./utils/setAuthToken";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

import store from "./store/store";

import Dashboard from "./components/app/Dashboard";
import HomePage from "./components/homepage/HomePage";
import Navbar from "./components/common/Navbar";
import { UserDetails } from "./components/common/UserDetails";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { logoutUser } from "./store/actions/authActions";
import { setCurrentUser } from "./store/actions/usersActions";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("user");

      console.log("token available");
      const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
      var currentTime = Date.now().toString();
      currentTime = currentTime.substring(0, currentTime.length - 3);
      const currentTimeNum = parseInt(currentTime);
      if (currentTimeNum > decoded.exp) {
        console.log("logged out");
        setAuthToken();
        store.dispatch(logoutUser());
        window.location.href = "/home-page";
      } else {
        console.log("logged in");
        setAuthToken(token);
        window.location.href = "/";
        store.dispatch(setCurrentUser());
      }
    } else {
      console.log("logged out");
      setAuthToken();
      window.location.href = "/home-page";
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/home-page" component={HomePage} exact />
              <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact />
              <Route path="/user/:username" component={UserDetails} exact />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: which of the if cases triggers the redirect each time?

Comment: I think window.location.href is causing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the BrowserRouter from App.js and put it above app by doing this in index.js ->

```
<BrowserRouter> <App> <BrowserRouter/>
```

and replace this

```
window.location.href = "/foo-bar"
```

with this

```
 this.props.history.push("/foo-bar")
```

or

```
this.props.history.replace("/foo-bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if the token is valid, you redirect the user to “/“ performing a browser refresh. This will trigger the entire webapp to reload and so App component componentDidMount to be called, the token will be valid again and the page will refresh again to "/".

Instead of using location.href you should use the history object:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // instead of window.location.href = 'some-url'
    history.push('/some-url');  
  }

  //..

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          {/* ... */}
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```